# wildfly10 add module using HTTP managment API

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

Is it possible to add module using wildfly HTTP management API?
I'm trying to recreate CLI command:

```
module add --name=com.oracle.jdbc --resources=/home/xyz/com/oracle/jdbc/main/ojdbc-7.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not. The `module` command only works on CLI and it only works if you're running the command from same server/workstation that WildFly is located on. It copies the file itself and writes the `module.xml`.